# vim in command line without open

Tags: vim

in vim, with

```
vim file +10
```

I can open the file in the line 10, with

```
vim file +10d
```

I can delete the line 10, but how I can delete the line and exit of vim? or how I can delete the line without open vim ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
vim file +10d -c wq
```

or

```
vim file +10d -c x
```

#### vim --help

```
 -c <command>        Execute <command> after loading the first file
```

Comment: to me it seems cleaner to write either 
`vim file +10d +x`
or `vim file -c 10d -c x`. Note: You can use up to 10 "+" or "-c" commands.

Answer (score 3):

To do that it would be better to use [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) like this:

```
sed -i 10d file
```

Comment: but, I like use the vim commands

Comment: you can execute multiple commands, but it will always open vim and then close. i suggested sed because you said "without open vim".  vim file -c 10d -c x